# How do I link two collections from a model to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a model defined:

```
public class ExhibitionItemModel
{
    public IEnumerable<tblItem> Items { get; set; }
    public tblExhibition Exhibition { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblExhibitionItem> ExhibitionItems { get; set; }
}
```

`tblItem` contains information about a specific item, e.g., description, code, etc.
`tblExhibitionItem` contains an id from `tblItem`, an exhibition id tells the system for which exhibitionm a specific item belongs, and a price for that item/exhibition combination.

In my Controller, I am populating ExhibitionItemModel:

```
ExhibitionItemModel exhibitionItemModel = new ExhibitionItemModel();
exhibitionItemModel.Exhibition = db.tblExhibitions.Find(id);
exhibitionItemModel.ExhibitionItems = (from objExhibitionItems in db.tblExhibitionItems
                                               where objExhibitionItems.ExhibitionID == id
                                               select objExhibitionItems).AsEnumerable<tblExhibitionItem>();

exhibitionItemModel.Items = (from objItem in db.tblItems
                                     select objItem).OrderBy(item => item.Code).AsEnumerable<tblItem>();

return View(exhibitionItemModel);
```

Im my view, I list out all the items and I want to have a checkbox which is selected according to whether the item is in `tblExhibitionItem`. Then a textbox to enter the price for the item.

So far, I have:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.AdditionalItem.Value, new { @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBox("chkIsSelected")</td>
            <td>@Html.Editor("txtPrice")</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

As I am a newbie to MVC, I am stuck as to how I establish the link between the checkbox and the Price textbox for an ExhibitionItem to that of the Item. In other words, when I commit the changes to a database, I am populating the ExhibitionItems with the ID of the Item and the Price, depending on whether the Checkbox ("chkIsSelected") is selected.

Additionally, what do I need to change to get the checkbox and Price populated if there are already exhibitionitems in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using ajax.

You need to figure out what checkbox is for what value. So the best way to link it is by using the **ID**.

So your checkbox code may look like this:

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("chkIsSelected", new { @value = item.ID })</td>
```

Now you'd use jquery to get an array of selected checkbox ids, and pass that to your controller.

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedItems = new Array(); // Create Array

    // Add to array
    $('#chkIsSelected:checked').each(function() { selectedItems.push($(this).val()); });

    $.ajax({
          url: '/update-exhibition-item',
          data: { items: selectedItems },
          traditional: true,
          success:function (data) {
                // do something.
          });
    });

});
```

Now you have to read this into your controller. This could be a partialview, or a proper view with results. It's up to you. Regardless, you'd cycle through the array and update each value that exists in the array. e.g.

```
[ActionName("update-exhibition-item")]
public ActionResult UpdateExhibition(int[] items)
{
     var list = from a in tableA
                where items.Contains(a.id)
                select a;
     // etc.
}
```